# NAudio doesn't output sound to my headphones only my speakers

Tags: c#, audio, output, naudio

I've been programming a soundplayer that uses the NAudio package for C# and one day the sound stopped outputting to my headphones and only works when i either remove the headphones or set the output device on windows to my speakers.

I've already tried setting the output device in my code to -1,0,1,2, and nnone of them seem to work. I thought this could've been caused by the addition of a third output device (a monitor with embedded speakers) so i disabled the monitor output and even removed the HDMI cable but it still won't work.

I've set the Naudio up like so:

```cs
   public static WaveOutEvent waveOut;
   public static MediaFoundationReader reader;
   reader = new MediaFoundationReader(Data.selectedPath);

   waveOut = new WaveOutEvent();

   waveOut.Init(reader);

   waveOut.Play();
```

Is there any reason as to why this happens? Because it used to work fine before.

Comment: Try changing waveOut.DeviceNumber
[upd] also you may check out the comments in source files: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/WaveOutEvent.cs

Comment: @DimaRich i've already tried changing the output to -1,0,1,2 as stated in the question and one of them work.

Comment: you may add a choice to choose a device to send audio to. Get the number of devices and then send to -1, 0, 1, 2 ... or (number-1)